# Converting CompletableFuture to Kotlin counterpart

Tags: java, kotlin

I've been trying to convert some Java code into Kotlin, but I am having trouble when it comes to CompletableFuture.  I have the following code:

```java
public CompletableFuture<Integer> updateAsync(@NotNull String sqlStatement, @NotNull SQLConsumer<PreparedStatement> psPreparer) throws UncheckedSQLException
{
    return CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> this.update(sqlStatement, psPreparer), this.threadPool);
}
```

I usually leverage the Java to Kotlin conversion tool within Intelij, but when I do it for this, it converts it but still uses CompleteableFuture.

What is the Kotlin equivalent to using CompleteableFuture that would not require too much refactoring?  Or, should I just keep using CompletableFuture in Kotlin?

Thank you

Comment: Yes, you can still use `CompletableFuture`. If using full power of Kotlin, so coroutines, you could/should use `Deferred`/`CompletableDeferred` or better, turn this function into a suspend function. But moving to coroutines is definitely more work than just replacing code here and there.

Comment: Alright.  This is a library, so If i was to implement coroutines here and then try to use this library in Java, would it work?

Comment: You can use coroutines in Kotlin and then provide adaptation layer for Java which would use `CompletableFuture`. In Kotlin you can fairly easily switch between futures and coroutines. However, coroutines is really a much bigger thing than just a class for wrapping asynchronous operations. I definitely don't want to discourage you, coroutines are awesome and much more reliable than other async patterns. However, they have their own learning curve and that really sounds more like reworking your whole library instead of just porting to another language.

Comment: Anyway, there is nothing wrong in using executors, `CompletableFuture` and stuff like that in Kotlin. This way the code is not multiplatform, but this is not a code smell or something.

Comment: Okay.  So I guess it's just easier to keep using CompletableFuture since it just works in both languages and no need for an adaptation layer?

Comment: @ThomasFry If you want your library to be used by both Kotlin users and Java users, I would probably provide both options. Because not having coroutine support might turn Kotlin users away.